# Flyway migration fails with Kotlin

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, flyway

Im playing with moving our spring boot app from java to kotlin. 
The issue i have is when the app starts, it runs the flyway migration script which fails:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO types VALUES ('some-id', 'xx', 'xxxxx');
```

However, the Java spring boot app works fine?

Removing the IGNORE fixes the issue. But I'm not sure why it fails with kotlin but works with java.

error:

```
-------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT IGNORE[*] INTO TYPES VALUES ('some-id', 'xx', 'xxxxx') "; expected "INTO"; SQL statement:
INSERT IGNORE INTO attribute_types VALUES ('some-id', 'xx', 'xxxx') [42001-199]
```

Answer (score 2):

could be you have not proper column  matching try use eplicit column clause

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO types (col1_for_some_id, col2_for_xx , col3_for_xxxx) 
VALUES ('some-id', 'xx', 'xxxxx');
```

Comment: just checked its h2

Comment: in h2 insert ignore  into is not allowed